# Почему не закрашивается карточка при фокусе ссылки

Tags: html, css

[image]

Есть данная карточка, почему при фокусе ссылки не закрашивается нижняя часть в нужный мне цвет?

```
<li class="section-playlist__item">
          <div class="section-playlist__card">
            <div class="section-playlist__img section-playlist__seventh-img">
              <svg class="section-playlist__card-flag" width="24" height="20" viewBox="0 
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="section-playlist__card-info">
              <p>Ploho</p>
              <a class="section-playlist__card-link" href="">3 последних альбома</a>
            </div>
          </div>
</li>
```

Фокус:

```
.section-playlist__card-link:focus-visible .section-playlist__item {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: потомучто вы не выложил весь код в вопросе)

Comment: @ПростаMiha Вроде всё необходимое выложил, чего не хватает? Просто боюсь много кода вставлять, так как может не пропустить

Comment: у вас `svg` не полный стоит, поправьте пж

Comment: @ПростаMiha, так вроде же хватает всего. Важно, что средствами CSS нет (пока что) возможности обращаться через дочерний `.section-playlist__card-link` элемент к родительскому `.section-playlist__item`

Comment: @ПростаMiha это я спецом убрал, чтобы код сократить, это флаг в верхнем правом углу, он тут не нужен в данном вопросе

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st можете подсказать, а как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: Ну ответ я написал, конечно. Но, признаюсь, для меня всегда это выглядело странно) На практике я стараюсь такого избегать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, конечно, решить эту проблему вот так:

```css
.section-playlist__card-link::before {/*создаём псевдоэлемент для ссылки, чтобы в будущем при фокусе на ней, иметь возможность менять этот псевдоэлемент (НО!)*/
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.section-playlist__card-link:focus-visible::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.section-playlist__item {/*(То самое НО!) Родителем для псевдоэлемента ссылки делаем карточку playlist'а*/
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<li class="section-playlist__item">
  <div class="section-playlist__card">
    <div class="section-playlist__img section-playlist__seventh-img">
      <svg class="section-playlist__card-flag" width="24" height="20" viewBox="0" </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="section-playlist__card-info">
      <p>Хорошо</p>
      <a class="section-playlist__card-link" href="">3 последних (или не очень) альбома</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```